# Postgresql. Убрать дубликаты записей

Tags: sql, postgresql

Структура таблицы:

```
id, sensor_id, t100, dt (timestamp)
```

В неё записываются измерения с датчиков. Но для одного и того же sensor_id могут быть повторяющиеся сподряд t100.
Как удалить по такому принципу:

```
Если следующая (по полю dt timestamp) запись для одного sensor_id
равна предыдущей, то удалить
```

Например:

```
87    2    3150    2018-05-08 15:11:45
88    2    3156    2018-05-08 15:11:47
89    2    3156    2018-05-08 15:11:49
90    2    3156    2018-05-08 15:11:51
91    2    3162    2018-05-08 15:11:53
92    2    3168    2018-05-08 15:11:55
93    2    3168    2018-05-08 15:11:57
94    2    3168    2018-05-08 15:11:59
95    2    3168    2018-05-08 15:12:01
96    2    3168    2018-05-08 15:12:03
97    2    3175    2018-05-08 15:12:06
```

Тут нужно удалить строки 89, 90, 93-96.

Я, конечно, могу написать скрипт по крону, который будет перебирать значения и удалять такие дубликаты, но может быть есть более правильные решения?

Comment: Это - лог, назначение которого - хранить ВСЕ данные. Идеологически неверно удалять записи - при этом теряется информация о времени получения информации с датчика. Скажем, удалив запись с id=90, Вы в будущем не сможете определить, было измерение с датчика 2 в 2018-05-08 15:11:51 или нет. *может быть есть более правильные решения?* ИМХО более правильное решение - ничего не удалять. А если нужно получить компактную таблицу для последующей обработки - то или копировать "почищенные" от излишков записи в другую таблицу, или получать такую выборку в запросах (возможно, оформив как представление).

Comment: @Akina, Мне как раз и не нужно хранить такие "дубликаты" измерений. Датчиков сотни, записей много, таблицы растут, а мне нужно хранить всё довольно компактно. Состояние системы, где в том числе будут записываться неудачные снятия измерений хранятся в другом месте. Вопрос в удалении таких дубликатов, а не в обсуждении нужности такого удаления.

Comment: В таком случае куда как разумнее такие данные просто не записывать в таблицу. Как именно она пополняется?

Comment: @Akina, пополняется демоном. Но у меня, возможно, слишком замороченная схема данных. Я для скорости работы опроса датчиков и принятия решений на основе измерений сначала скидываю данные в redis, а уже потом из redis раз в N секунд данные забираю и заливаю в sql. Вот и думаю на каком этапе убирать дубликаты и один из вариантов это чистить sql периодически или написать триггер на INSERT.

Comment: *пополняется демоном* Вероятно, демон выполняет некий INSERT-запрос, типа `INSERT INTO log (fields) VALUES (values)`, верно? Модифицируйте запрос до состояния `INSERT INTO log (sensor_id, t100, dt) SELECT @sensor_id, @t100, @dt WHERE @t100  NOT IN (SELECT t100 FROM log WHERE sensor_id=@sensor_id ORDER BY dt DESC LIMIT 1)`. Запись будет  выполнена только в случае, когда для этого датчика состояние не равно предыдущему.

Comment: @Akina, Спасибо! Сейчас только к sqlalchemy это попытаюсь прикрутить ))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
delete from t where id in
(select id from
(select id, t100-lag(t100) over(partition by sensor_id order by dt) n from t) X
where n=0);
```

Comment: Работает! Спасибо большое! Сейчас буду разбираться с тем КАК он работает )